# key does not exist during CryptographicException when using egypt eta certificate

Tags: x509certificate, sign

```
    Dim textToSign As String = vstrToHash
    Dim contentI As Byte()
    contentI = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToSign)
    Dim contentInfo As New ContentInfo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToSign))
    Dim signedCms As New SignedCms(contentInfo, False)
    Dim certificateFromFile = New X509Certificate2("d:\preprod-root-ca.crt")
    Dim certWithKey = certificateFromFile.GetRSAPublicKey
    Dim Signer As CmsSigner = New CmsSigner(certificateFromFile)
         'Signer.DigestAlgorithm = New System.Security.Cryptography.Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1") 'sha256

    signedCms.ComputeSignature(Signer, False)
```

get key does not exist on last command and the certificate has no private key

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, because `.crt` file contains only public key and do not store private key which is required for signing. Certificate with embedded private key often has `.p12` or `.pfx` file extension and often are protected with password, so you will need to use `X509Certificate2` constructor which accepts a password as a parameter.

Comment: The Api supplier (eta egypt) provide only the .crt file to install on trsuted root certification used to sign the json message before sending it

Comment: this is not sufficient. They have to provide a private key as well. You may need to reach them for additional support.

Comment: thks, will invetigate about that. and let u know